# Connecting my Android device with Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015

I have compiled a sample Android project with Visual Studio 2015 (RC - Community Edition), now I would like to deploy and execute it on my connected android device.
ADB seems to be working:

- "adb devices" is showing my device "CB5A1N42TN      device"
- using the menu "Tools / Android / Android Devices Monitor" tools I am able to see the connected device
- in Android Studio, I am able to deploy and run my app on the device

But in Visual Studio 2015, when executing the project I have the following error message:

```
1>Error installing the package. The device '' is invalid or not running.  <...>
```

So I suppose I should input my device somewhere, but I can't find that place in the options available.
 I also noticed that on the dropdown menu for the execution there is a "No devices available" message.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am curious why the question was down voted, if there is a reason please let me know so that I don't ask this type of question again. Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my Android Galaxy S6 and my platform is set to ARM.

Comment: Then it should work, does everything else is the same? Have you try with the RTM version of Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I found the answer , hopefully it will help others.

The configuration was pointing to "X86", once I selected "ARM" then the device appeared in the list of targets I could run the app on.

Comment: I wish I was that lucky, my Nexus 6 simply wont show up in the list, giving me the exact samt error message you had.

Comment: @ViktorSehr did you find a solution? I have the same problem with lg g3

Comment: I dont remember what I did to solve it, but maybe I hadnt but the device on developer mode or installed the android drivers on the pc.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the Settings screen  in your android phone
2. Select **Developer options**
3. most importantly make sure **USB debugging option** is checked

hopefully your USB drivers are installed and for further details go to [this page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/)